# Shower at a truck stop for a couple travelling in car

Tags: usa, stopovers

We are a couple travelling to Chicago from Boston in our SUV. Just wondering if it is safe to stop for a shower at one of the truck stops like Loves. How much does it cost for a family of two to shower? Is the cost based on hour of usage or per person? Is it also possible to park for a few hours and sleep in our car at these stops? How much is the parking fee?

Comment: It has been a long time since I used a truck stop shower (usually after coming out of the wilderness), but they sure seem to be pretty busy and a quite standard part of travel plaza services. Cost used to be for a person for a period of time (so they could schedule showers during busy periods).

Comment: It's fairly common to sleep at a truckstop (I've even managed to catch a nap in the truckers' lounge on occasion) and you won't be charged anything to park. Expect to pay between $5-$15 per person for a shower.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find prices online in many cases but $15 is a start.

Yes, anyone can reserve and use the shower facilities at truck stops.  Most people are actually surprised at how nice they are.  They are typically cleaned and replenished after every use.  You can ask specifically about this.

Most facilities use shower suites, like full private bathrooms, so a couple using the same facility is not likely a problem.  Many couples run long-haul together so this is not an uncommon scenario.

Comment: I agree the showers at Pilot and Love's stops have been very clean and secure.  The ones I've used have been suites with more than enough room for a family.